# How can I use an apostrophe in a send-hook for mutt?

Tags: mutt

I'm trying to set up a send-hook in mutt, with a sender with an apostrophe in it. This is legitimate in the [username part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816424/are-single-quotes-legal-in-the-name-part-of-an-email-address) at least. I have the following in `muttrc`.

```
send-hook '~t "^foo@bar\\.com$"' 'set from="Jon O'Connor <jon.o\'connor@bar.com>"'
```

However, when I compose an email to `foo@bar.com`, it's from `Jon OConnor <jon.o'connor@bar.com>`. The username is correct, but the "Real name" is not. I've tried a varying amount of backslashes in front of the apostrophe in the real name, but cannot make mutt print it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this the same way you'd do it in your shell: use `'\''`.

Read that as: exit from the initial single-quote `'`, then `\'` (i.e. a backslash-escaped `'`), and then a new single-quote `'` for the rest of the string.

So, try this:

```
send-hook '~t "^foo@bar\\.com$"' 'set from="Jon O'\''Connor <jon.o\'connor@bar.com>"'
```

I tested this in my own `~/.muttrc` (without the folder-hook) and sent a test message to myself.  It works:

`From: Craig O'Sanders <cas@taz.net.au>`

Comment: Thanks, that works! Mutt escaping is a total mystery to me. I don't understand why this is necessary for the "real name" and not for the "username"…